# Celery: per task concurrency limits (# of workers per task)?

Tags: celery, django-celery

Is it possible to set the concurrency (the number of simultaneous workers) on a per-task level in [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)? I'm looking for something more fine-grained that `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` (that sets the concurrency for the whole daemon).

The usage scenario is: I have a single celerlyd running different types of tasks with very different performance characteristics - some are fast, some very slow. For some I'd like to do as many as I can as quickly as I can, for others I'd like to ensure only one instance is running at any time (ie. concurrency of 1).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [automatic routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing) to route tasks to different queues which will be processed by celery workers with different concurrency levels.

> celeryd-multi start fast slow -c:slow 3 -c:fast 5

This command launches 2 celery workers listening *fast* and *slow* queues with 3 and 5 concurrency levels respectively.

> CELERY_ROUTES = {"tasks.a": {"queue": "slow"}, "tasks.b": {"queue":
>   "fast"}}

The tasks with type tasks.a will be processed by *slow* queue and tasks.b tasks by *fast* queue respectively.

Comment: Thanks 0x00mh. So I can define concurrency on queues, but not on tasks. And I believe this means I'm starting multiple celery daemons. So I guess that means there's no way to set the per-task concurrency without using a separate daemon?

Comment: CELERYD_CONCURRENCY defines how many processes (worker processes) to launch. Worker processes consume messages from the broker independently. Message contains the task name to execute.